# Arm64- why all filled with 1 the lower 32bit? Isn't it should be only 1 value?

Tags: assembly, arm64, twos-complement, sign-extension

```
mov x0, #1000

mov w6, #-1
add x7,x0,x6, sxtw
```

what will be the value of x6 and x7? [In hex]
Here ans x6=0xffffffff //why all value of lower half filled with 1?
and how sxtw work when the ans will be 999 in decimal. I want to know details how this happening.

Comment: But, do you know about two's complement arithmetic?  As 32 bit numbers, `-1` and `0xffffffff` are the same.

Comment: yeah type mistake

Comment: Can you explain a little more how it become

Comment: The idea is that the bit pattern `0xffffffff` can be used to represent the integer -1, because adding `0xffffffff` to any 32-bit number (and ignoring any carry) has exactly the same mathematical effect as adding -1 (i.e. it subtracts 1).  Try some examples.

Comment: 000000000000000000000001 need full 32bit 2s. I got it now

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: But anyway, the comments section of this question is not the place for me to teach you about two's complement representations.  It is a very standard and fundamental concept, and you ought to read about it in a standard textbook.

Comment: Thanks I got it now but 3rd statement code i did not found in book mean sxtw

Comment: You can look up the instruction in any instruction set reference, such as the official Architecture Reference Manual.  It takes the low 32 bits of x6, [sign extends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension) to a 64-bit value, adds that value to x0, and places the result into x7.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it all. Should i delete my question now?

Comment: Either that, or else write your own answer to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
// 1= 000000000000000000000001 (On 32bit)
// -1= 111111111111111111111111
// So -1 in hex = 0xffffffff
```

The lower half of x6 will be filled with above value.

On 3rd statement it sign extends the value to 64bit so -1 is correct then it add 1000+(-1) and become value 999